# dplyr error - grouped ntile fails when first group is all NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I noticed that when I apply the dplyr (v0.4.3) ntile function by group, and all of the values in the first group are NA, the result for everything in the third group also becomes NA. This is a weird bug (?) which only happens when the first group is NA.

Simple example below - The expected behavior is that ntile will rank all of the NA values in group "a" as NA, but it also ranks group"c" as NA even though it contains no NA values. If I move the NA values to group "b" the function works as expected.

```
x <- data.frame(group = rep(c("a","b","c","d"), 5), value = 1:20)
x$value <- ifelse(x$group == "a", NA, x$value)
x %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(quintile = ntile(value, 5))

# Source: local data frame [20 x 3]
# Groups: group [4]
# 
#     group value quintile
#    (fctr) (int)    (int)
# 1       a    NA       NA
# 2       b     2        1
# 3       c     3       NA
# 4       d     4        1
# 5       a    NA       NA
# 6       b     6        2
# 7       c     7       NA
# 8       d     8        2
# 9       a    NA       NA
# 10      b    10        3
# 11      c    11       NA
# 12      d    12        3
# 13      a    NA       NA
# 14      b    14        4
# 15      c    15       NA
# 16      d    16        4
# 17      a    NA       NA
# 18      b    18        5
# 19      c    19       NA
# 20      d    20        5
```

For background, I am date-lagging stock data, which creates NA for all values on the first date. Then when I then quintile grouped by date, the ranking function doesn't work correctly.

Many thanks in advance,
Alex Ryer

Comment: Well, i'm stumped. I can reproduce the problem and it exists regardless of row order or `ntile` groups.

Comment: i am using dplyr_0.4.2 i do not get the error. i get quintile = NA  1  1  1 NA  2  2  2 NA  3  3  3 NA  4  4  4 NA  5  5  5

Comment: u might want to raise an issue at https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues

Comment: I also use 0.4.2 and the problem does not reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the development version [per hadley's comment on the issue OP filed](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1769)